# Rails routing params mismatch error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am adding excel import feature but I am getting error. `:id` params is getting passed instead of `:project_id` params.

Below is my code-

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag import_project_stages_path ,multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>

<%end %>
```

**stage_controller.rb**

```
def import
    Stage.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice:"Projects imported. "
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :projects do
    resources :stages do
      collection {post :import}
    end
  end
```

**error**

> No route matches {:action=>"import", :controller=>"stages", :id=>"1"},
> missing required keys: [:project_id]

Comment: Why you are using nested routes, because of that you are getting this error to solve this either pass the project_id or make routes without scope of projects.

you can check by **rake routes** also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested resources will produce a route path that looks like `<host>/projects/:project_id/stages`. So, you need to include the parent project ID as part of the path in your `form_tag`. You can do that by including the project as a parameter to the URL helper method:

```
<%= form_tag import_project_stages_path(@project), multipart: true do %>
  ...
<%end %>
```